# Keeping CSV format via Jquery $,get

Tags: jquery, html, csv

I am grabbing a large CSV file via Jquery get.  I want to try putting that input between two html tags.  However, I am losing the new lines.  I CANNOT have a br tag separating the lines, as it needs to be read like a csv file would.  It needs to remain looking like this if you were to view the source:

```
<pre>
  1,2
  1,3
  1,4
</pre>
```

Any thoughts on how to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

For CSVs use `\r\n` instead of `<br>`